# Importing SignalR.Redis package cause SignalR errors

Tags: redis, signalr

I have a working application using SignalR hubs with a single web instance. I need to extend the functionality to a web farm. So I am trying to use the SignalR.Redis package. After I import that package with Package Manager in VS 2010 I start getting the following 500 error in the webpage/client:

```
[22:53:21.615] GET http://localhost:2936/signalr/hubs [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 31ms]
```

Before importing the SignalR.Redis package that call works fine. I have changed no actual code yet. Just imported the package. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scratch this question. I started over, updating all SignalR packages in VS 2010 and everything works. Must have been a outdated package or something. Thanks.